# Why are there big empty sections in compiled code?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, machine-code

I don't know much about how compilers work, except that compiled code starts with the data first and instructions afterwards.

I was playing around with the terminal, and noticed something peculiar when looking at the output from `xxd /usr/bin/xmail`. There are just big blocks left blank.

[image: Terminal xxd output screenshot]

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Use [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) and [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/reaedelf.1.html) to explore your ELF executable. Use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) to understand the virtual address space of a process. Your question is too broad, and operating system specific.

Comment: Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)